# How to save image metadata in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to make an image gallery. For this purpose i'm storing the original images (right now about 7000 and in future there will be over 60.000) in the storage laravel path. 
Next i make a job that stores the path and metadata(image size, resolution, mimetype, width and height) to db.

The problem is its very very slow.

this is my controller:

```
 public function startJob() {

        // Start doing Jobs
        CreateDirectories::withChain([
            new RecordPaths,
            // new OptimizeImage,
            // new SendNotification,
        ])->dispatch()->delay(now()->addSeconds(3));
        echo 'create directories and stored paths to database!';
    }
```

In my controller i make some jobs.
First it will make a directory where i'm storing thumbs. After this job is done the next one is RecordPaths to the DB.

And here is the problem it is very slow (image/2sec).

this is my job:

```
class RecordPaths implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

        public function handle()
        {
            $this->truncate();

            $files = Storage::disk('gallery')->allFiles();
            foreach($files as $file) {
                $thumb = new Thumb;
                $thumb->brand = explode("/", $file, 2)[0];
                $thumb->name = array_slice(explode("/", $file),-1)[0];
                $thumb->path = $file;
                //
                $thumb->size = $this->imageMetadata($file, 'fileSize');
                $thumb->width = $this->imageMetadata($file, 'imageWidth');
                $thumb->height = $this->imageMetadata($file, 'imageHeight');
                $thumb->mime = $this->imageMetadata($file, 'mimeType');
                //
                $thumb->save();
            }
        }

        public function truncate() {
            return Thumb::truncate();
        }

        public function imageMetadata($file, $type) {
            $metaData = [];
            $metaData['mimeType'] = \Image::make(storage_path("app\public\gallery\\") . $file)->exif('MimeType');
            $metaData['fileSize'] = \Image::make(storage_path("app\public\gallery\\") . $file)->exif('FileSize');
            $metaData['imageWidth'] = \Image::make(storage_path("app\public\gallery\\") . $file)->exif('ExifImageWidth');
            $metaData['imageHeight'] = \Image::make(storage_path("app\public\gallery\\") . $file)->exif('ExifImageLength');
            return $metaData[$type];
        }
    }
```

the `$files = Storage::disk('gallery')->allFiles();` in the handle method return this:
[image]

and my db after some insers:
[image]

Do have anybody any idea how to speed it up ?

Comment: Multithreading?

Comment: @FrankerZ with laravel? :P

Comment: "Storage::disk('gallery')->allFiles();" <- *all* files? It kind of looks like you're repeating the process for every image you have, rather than only the unprocessed ones. If that's the case it's no wonder it's slow.

Comment: @Stratadox hmm shoud i save "Storage::disk('gallery')->allFiles();"  into an array before i'm interating ?

Comment: Uhh no you just should't repeat the process for the files you've already handled. I might misread the process, but it looks like you're processing 7000 images every time you upload 1. If that's indeed the case, you can speed it up 7000 times by not doing all that double work.

Comment: can you give me some simple example ? If i don't save the metadata. The iterating part to save file paths into the db takes 3sec.

Answer (score 1):

First of all do only one `\Image::make` instead of 4, then just call ->exif method with params.
Second, replace `$thumb->save();` with batch inserting. You can use [this](https://github.com/mavinoo/laravelBatch) library or write own code (look [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#inserts)).
P.S. It will increase your execution time.
P.S.S. Also you can try to use laravel chunks or split images between few job workers.